# Unrealistic predicted values from estimated ARMAProcess

Tags: numerics

I am trying to predict future outcomes, using an ARMAProcess, however, the results I get, based on the data I have provided, are totally unrealistic.

This is the data set I have `england = {1.37, 1.34, 1.35, 1.38}`

This is what I did to try and find the parameters for the ARMAProcess:

```
EstimatedProcess[england, ARMAProcess[{a}, {b}, v]]
```

Which gave me this result

```
ARMAProcess[{1.08516}, {-1.1008}, 0.000674961, {}]
```

Then, when generating new values from it, I get this:

```
samplearma = RandomFunction[ARMAProcess[{1.08516}, {-1.1008}, 0.000674961, {}], {0, 20}]
```

Which gave me these numbers:

```
{{-0.0198782, 0.00230837, -0.0115471, -0.0136337, 
  0.00551491, -0.0194912, 0.0162183, -0.00752205, -0.00972862, 
  0.00416869, 0.0108114, -0.000886337, -0.00808999, 
  0.00990031, -0.00662776, 0.0328873, 0.0230488, 
  0.00817235, -0.0172371, -0.0369344, -0.0399351}}
```

As you can see, these numbers are very unrealistic (negative terms should not be possible), in terms of the original dataset ''england'' that I had. The goal is to make a model, accurately predicting future values based on this dataset. Obviously I have done something wrong but I cant figure out what. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: Phrases such as "I don't know what I'm doing..." or "Here is a problem that I have..." or "Please help me solve this problem..." and such carry no content and should be eliminated.  Just state the content of the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question - it's well formatted and clearly describes the problem. I have edited the title.

Comment: The main issue seems to me to be thinking that one can obtain good estimates of 3 parameters with only 4 data points.  To check on whether your code is OK, generate lots of data from known parameters and see if the estimates are then reasonable.

Comment: Maybe: `ListLinePlot@
 RandomFunction[Normal[TimeSeriesModelFit[england]], {0, 20}]` ?

Comment: Mariusz Iwaniuk - Amazing! Thank you so much!